# JRE not found In Nokia SDK 2.0 with Netbeans 7.3

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, java-me, nokia-s40

I Want to develop `J2ME` mobile Application with `Nokia SDK 2.0` and as i successfully install `Netbeans 7.3` with `J2ME` and here i add the platform.
`Tools -> Java Platform -> Add Platform -> Java ME CLDC Platform Emulator`.

and it automatically found the installed `Nokia SDK` located in C drive. and when i clicked on Next it show an Error.

[image]

If anyone knows about it please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced the same problem and you need to install jdk-6u17-windows-i586  bit and try.

Answer (score 1):

What OS do you use?
Do you use 32/64 bit OS?

I also had this problem before.

I use Windows 8 64 bit. I have installed Jdk and jre x64 bit and couldn't add nokia 2.0 sdk to my netbeans.

But after i tried to install jre 32 bit to my computer. It started to detect my jre installation and now i can use nokia 2.0 sdk in my windows 8

Comment: i have 64bit with Window7 and from your point of view i need to install 32 bit jre ?

Answer (score 1):

Install Java 1.7 for x86 (32 Bit), works fine for me then. (Nokia SDK is 32 bit, and have compatibility issue with 64 Bit JRE)